# What does the asterisk (*) do in \arabic*?

Tags: counters, enumitem

I was wondering what the **'*'** (asterisk) does in the command `\arabic*`?

My code:

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\textbf{\arabic*})]
    \item Text 1
    \item Text 2
    \item Text 3
\end{enumerate*}
```

The asterisk after `enumerate*` puts the lists as part of the text flow. However, `\arabic*` without the asterisk would throw an error.

Can somebody explain why the asterisk must be entered?

Comment: it is better if you always provide a complete small example document, in this case I happened to recognise the syntax so could answer but the form you show is not defined by default, just in the contributed enumitem  package, which you didn't mention you were using.

Comment: Actually, this is described in the manual. Reading manuals does not hurt ;-)

Comment: It refers to the item counter, which is goes by different names in different packages or levels.  Normal latex uses enumi, enumii, enumiii and enumiv, but enumitem stores the name of the counter in `\@listctr`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the standard use of the command the use is `\arabic{section}` where the argument is the name of a counter to be printed in arabic. The `*` is a special form defined by the `enumitem` package for use in its optional argument where `*` denotes the value of the current item label counter.

Comment: So the * is basically a "catch all" instruction. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Alex_P not really catch all, it is specifically catch the counter that is being used as specified by other options to this list's setup.